# Combining NodeJS files

Tags: node.js, modular

Standard NodeJS app utilising module.exports to make the code modular.  We'd like to combine all of those files together into a single file a la RequireJS on the client side (which is what we use there).  Does anyone know an easy way to do this server-side without wrapping everything in more module wrappers (e.g. RequireJS) e.g. command-line tool ?

Ta

N

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use node.js  modules on the client side without additional wrappers (like RequireJS), you'll want to look into using browserify:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

It's a very useful build tool that allows you to use node-style `require()` statements and native node.js modules on the client side. Or, to quote from the github page itself:

> Make node-style require() work in the browser with a server-side build step, as if by magic!

Comment: Nice plug - completely fails to address the question but nice plug nevertheless :)